# max count for count(*)

Tags: mysql

My table structure is

```
| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
| uid        | char(255) | NO   |     |                   |       |
| lid        | char(255) | NO   | MUL |                   |       |
| ip_address | char(15)  | NO   |     |                   |       |
| user_agent | char(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| open_date  | timestamp | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| referrer   | char(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| environ    | text      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| country    | char(255) | NO   | MUL |                   |       |
```

I want to query for max clicks recored in a particular day of a month

Query

```
select count(open_date) as c,day(open_date) as d
from link_click 
where month(open_date)="01" and year(open_date)="2011" 
group by d
having c =MAX(c);
```

but it's resulting empty set.

Pls. suggest.

Comment: This is not IM, you don't have to put every sentence or clause in its own line.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

```
select count(open_date) as c,day(open_date) as d
from link_click 
where month(open_date)="01" and year(open_date)="2011" 
group by d
order by c desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I think you'll need to `GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)`.

Comment: @Bobby isn't that the `group by d`?

Comment: mysql> select count(open_date) as c,day(open_date) as d
    -> from
    -> link_click
    -> where
    -> month(open_date)="01" and year(open_date)="2011"
    -> group by d order by c desc limit 1;

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
select * from (
  select count(open_date) as c,day(open_date) as d
  from link_click 
  where month(open_date)="01" and year(open_date)="2011" 
  group by d)
having c =MAX(c);
```

Comment: mysql> select count(open_date) as c,day(open_date) as d
    -> from
    -> link_click
    -> where
    -> month(open_date)="01" and year(open_date)="2011"
    -> group by d order by c desc limit 1;

Comment: What do you mean by this? I checked, and found your comment to be equal to **JohnC** 's answer. Does this mean that his answer is working for you? If so, you should accept his answer by clicking the big tick mark on the left of his answer.